# Why "web3.exceptions.ContractLogicError: execution reverted: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert" this error happened?

Tags: python, solidity, web3py

I'm making private blockchain using truffle, ganache, solidity 0.8.0 , web3.py(python)

I'm trying to upload file information on blockchain. file information is filehash, filename, filesize tec.

But there's something error.

```
web3.exceptions.ContractLogicError: execution reverted: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert
```

when i use this code, it worked.

```
tx_hash = CON_IDX.functions.upload("11", "22", "33", 44)
tx_hash: <Function upload(string,string,string,uint256) bound to ('11', '22', '33', 44)>
```

but when i use this code, it doesn't work.

```
tx_hash = CON_IDX.functions.upload("11", "22", "33", 44).transact()

web3.exceptions.ContractLogicError: execution reverted: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert
```

I thought there might be a problem with the smart contract, so I used remixide, but there was no problem.
[image]

why this error happened?.. please help me

Here is my entire code.
Owner_contract.py

```
import sys
import os
import time
import solcx
from solcx import compile_files
from logzero import logger
from web3 import Web3

w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider('http://127.0.0.1:7545')) # GANACHE
w3.eth.defaultAccount = w3.eth.accounts[0]
print('install solcx 0.8.0..')
solcx.install_solc('0.8.0')

def deploy(contract_file, contract_name):
    compiled_sol = compile_files([contract_file])
    interface = compiled_sol['{}:{}'.format(contract_file, contract_name)]
    
    contract = w3.eth.contract(abi=interface['abi'],
                    bytecode='0x'+interface['bin'],
                    bytecode_runtime=interface['bin-runtime'])

    tx_hash = contract.constructor(transaction={'from':w3.eth.accounts[0]}).transact()
    logger.info(f'Owner_tx_hash: {tx_hash}')
    
    tx_receipt = w3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(tx_hash)
    logger.info(f'Owner_tx_receipt: {tx_receipt}')
    
    contract_address = tx_receipt['contractAddress']
    logger.info(f'Owner_contract_address: {contract_address}')
    
    contract_instance = contract(contract_address)
    logger.info(f'Owner_contract_instance: {contract_instance}')

    return contract_instance
```

smartcontract.sol

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
//pragma solidity >=0.5.0 < 0.9.0;
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;
contract Owner {
    address public fileowner;
    
    /* 발신자의 값을 fileowner에 저장*/
    function Owned() public{
        fileowner = msg.sender;
    }
    /* modifier은 함수의 동작을 변경시키기 위해 사용 */
    /* _는 함수의 실행시점 -> 코드 추가시 _을 기준으로 작성*/
    /* require은 인자의 값이 false이면 즉시 함수 실행을 중단하고 모든 상태 변환을 되돌림*/
    modifier onlyOwner {
        require(msg.sender == fileowner); // check if fileowner same msg.sender
        _;
    }
    /* transferOwnership함수가 실행되면 onlyOwner함수가 실행되고 만약 require(false)이면 즉시 중단 */
    /* 아니면 새로운 owner을 fileowner로 바꾼다 */
    function transferOwnership(address newOwner) public onlyOwner { // if this function call, 
        fileowner = newOwner; // owner changed
    }
    
    /* 리턴 타입을 address(이더리움 주소)로 리턴 */
    function getOwner() public view returns (address) { // return fileowner(type: address)
        return fileowner;
    }
}

contract CopyInfoContract{
    uint index;
    struct CopyrightStruct {
        string Artist;
        string Createdtime; // When this file created
        string Type; // File Type ex) music, video, photo etc
        string Description; // Simple Description of file
        uint timestamp;
    }

    event Copyright(string Artist, string Createdtime, string Type, string Description, uint timestamp);
    
    CopyrightStruct[] public copyright; // dynamic size 

    function initalized() public{
        index = 0;
    }

    function addCopyright(string memory _Artist, string memory _Createdtime, string memory  _Type, string memory _Description, uint timestamp ) public {
        copyright.push(CopyrightStruct(_Artist, _Createdtime, _Type, _Description, timestamp));
        index++;
        emit Copyright(_Artist, _Createdtime, _Type, _Description, timestamp);
    }
    
    function getCopyright(uint _idx) public view returns(string memory, string memory, string memory, string memory) {
        return (copyright[_idx].Artist, copyright[_idx].Createdtime, copyright[_idx].Type, copyright[_idx].Description);
    }
    
}

contract StorefileHash is Owner {
    struct File {
        string filename;
        uint UploadDate;
        uint Filesize;
    }
    
        
    mapping(string => File) private files; // string : key, File : Value
    mapping(string => string[]) private fileOwners;
    string[] public owners;
    uint public ownerID = 0;
    
    event FileUpload(string ownername, string filehash, File file);
    
    function upload(string memory _ownername, string memory _filehash, string memory _filename, uint _filesize) onlyOwner public{
        ownerID++;
        owners.push(_ownername);
        File memory f = File(_filename, block.timestamp, _filesize); // now = block.timestamp
        files[_filehash] = f;
        emit FileUpload(_ownername, _filehash, f);
    }

    function Exsistcheck(string memory filehash) onlyOwner public view returns (bool) {
        if(files[filehash].Filesize > 0) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    
    function getOwnerName(uint id) onlyOwner public view returns (string memory) {
        return owners[id];
    }
    
    function getfileinfo(string memory filehash) onlyOwner public view returns (string memory, uint, uint) {
        return (files[filehash].filename, files[filehash].UploadDate, files[filehash].Filesize);
    }
}
```

uploadfile.py

```
import Owner_contract
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
from web3 import Web3
from logzero import logger

CON_IDX=None

CON_IDX = Owner_contract.deploy("smartcontract.sol", "StorefileHash")

def recvfile():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = request.files['file']
        filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
        path = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)
        file.save(path)
        logger.info(f'path: {path}')

        owner = "test_owner"
        filehash = str(sha256_checksum(path))
        filesize = 20#getsize(str(path))

        tx_hash = CON_IDX.functions.upload("11", "22", "33", 44)#.transact() #here is the error
        #logger.info(f'transaction: {transaction}')
        #logger.info(f'transcation_compo: {transaction.')
        logger.info(f'tx_hash: {tx_hash}')
        return 'file upload complete'
```